# What are the advantages for the Government of presenting policy in a general debate rather than as a ministerial statement?

Tags: united-kingdom, house-of-commons, procedure, liz-truss

[The i news this morning](https://inews.co.uk/news/politics/energy-announcement-time-when-watch-liz-truss-update-bills-plan-watch-live-1838687) says that Liz Truss plans to unveil her plan to attempt to tackle the energy crisis in Britain:

> Liz Truss will outline the Government’s plan to save households and businesses from soaring energy bills in a statement at the House of Commons on Thursday.
>
> The new Prime Minister confirmed that she would deliver the statement during the first PMQs of her premiership on Wednesday.

When I looked at the House of Commons [order paper for today](https://commonsbusiness.parliament.uk/Document/59089/Html), however, the policy isn't being announced in a statement at all, but rather as a general debate.

What are the advantages for Truss in presenting policy in this format, rather than as a ministerial statement?

Comment: Does it mean the statement does not have to be published in advance? https://mobile.twitter.com/RhonddaBryant/status/1567822229823492096

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a start, when the government gives a ministerial statement, there is a convention that MPs are given advance sight of it. When this convention is broken, which is rare, it's a fairly big deal - in 2017 when Theresa May gave a ministerial statement on the disaster at Grenfell Tower, [she apologised](https://www.gov.uk/government/speeches/pm-commons-statement-on-grenfell-tower-22-june-2017) to the Leader of the Opposition for the short notice he had of the statement, and in 2019 [MPs complained](https://twitter.com/KirstySNP/status/1105816639591903232) when the Chancellor's spring statement was heavily redacted. As the debate today is a general debate opened by the Prime Minister, the same convention does not hold; and the Leader of the Opposition and others will have little or no time to prepare a response to the government's plan. It seems from watching the beginning of the proceedings that copies of the statement were still being printed and distributed to MPs as Truss was speaking.

Secondly, although Liz Truss will open the debate, she will not face extended questioning on the plan. In a ministerial statement, once the opening speech is complete, MPs put questions to the government minister in succession until the Speaker considers the topic closed. As this is a general debate, once Liz Truss has finished speaking there will probably be speeches from the leaders of opposing parties, moving on to floor speeches from backbenchers - but they will not be able to question Truss directly.

At the end of the general debate, there will be a vote on the motion - in this case "That this House has considered UK Energy Costs". Usually these votes are 'nodded through' without the House dividing. It's possible that opposition parties may force a division on the motion, but there's no consequence to the vote passing or failing except symbolically. After a ministerial statement, there would be no vote.

So essentially it gives Truss the opportunity to continue developing the statement up to the last minute - as she doesn't need to provide MPs with advance sight of it; this in turn allows her to get the edge on opposition MPs as they will be unable to tailor their speeches to the policy in advance. Furthermore, she will not have to respond to questions on the policy but could leave the chamber directly after her opening speech, if she so wished.

The downside for the Government is that this will be viewed as an attempt to dodge scrutiny - for example, the Daily Mail (usually Tory-leaning) has the following comment:

> Liz Truss looks to be using a procedural tactic to avoid intense questioning on her energy bills announcement in the Commons.
>
> The PM is scheduled to lay out the plan during a 'general debate' rather than in a standard ministerial statement.
>
> That could mean she just takes a few interventions from MPs during her speech, rather than fielding a slew of questions until the Speaker decides the House is satisfied.

Furthermore, it's possible the opposition could make a symbolic protest vote against the motion - something they wouldn't be able to do if it was presented as a ministerial statement.

Comment: Didn't the speaker chastise her for trying to use this to bypass the convention?